# New to x86 (Adding)

Tags: x86

Can anyone double check this for me to see if I did it right?

```
 1. create the following variables in the data section. Declare them as WORD (not BYTE or DWORD)  
    num1 (initialize to 0FACE hex)  
    num2 (initialize to 0FEED hex)  
    In the code section write code to do the following:
2. You should populate the following registers with the following values in the following order:
    edx = 0D2C6FFFE hex  
    ebx = 0FFFFFFFFh  
    eax = 0FFFFFFFFh  
    bh = 249 decimal  
    bl = 11110111 binary  
    ecx = 0FFFFFFD3 hex  
3. After you populate the above registers you should evaluate the following expression:
    eax = bl + bh + cx + num1 + num2 + edx
```

I got that:

```
eax = 3,356,452,476 (base 10)
```

Code:

```
mov     edx, 0d2c6fffeh ;edx = 0d2c6fffeh
mov     ebx, 0ffffffffh ;ebx = 0ffffffffh
mov     eax, 0ffffffffh ;eax = 0ffffffffh
mov     bh,  249d       ;bh  = 249 (base 10) = 0f9h = 11111001b
mov     bl,  11110111b  ;bl  = 11110111b = 0f7h = 247 (base 10)
mov     ecx, 0ffffffd3h ;ecx = 0ffffffd3h

movzx   esi, bl         ;copy bl to si and zero out upper part of esi
mov     eax, esi        ;move eax to esi

movzx   esi, bh         ;copy bh to si and zero out upper part of esi
add     eax, esi        ;add eax to esi

movzx   esi, cx         ;copy cx to si and zero out upper part of esi
add     eax, esi        ;add eax to esi

movzx   esi, num1       ;copy num1 to si and zero out upper part of esi
add     eax, esi        ;add eax to esi

movzx   esi, num2       ;copy num2 to si and zero out upper part of esi
add     eax, esi        ;add eax to esi

add     eax, edx        ;add eax to edx
```

Is this correct? I wasn't sure if I was suppose to use mov or add for the first one (since eax is already set), and not sure if I added the variables right.

Comment: Do you want to check your homework?

Comment: So ... where's the code you wrote to do this? If you want us to check it, that would be a pre-requisite, I would imagine :-)

Comment: When you evaluate the expression in part3, are you supposed to do it with no truncation of temporary results?  Or is it supposed to be `uint8_t(bl+bh) + uint16_t(cx)` + ...  i.e. Are you supposed to zero-extend all those narrow inputs to 32 or 64 bits first, or start with `add bl, bh`?

Comment: I updated the post with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wasn't sure if I was suppose to use mov or add for the first one (since eax is already set),

Part 3 is pretty clear that the new value of EAX is not dependent on the old value, so `movzx eax, bl` would be a good way to start.  Your `movzx` + `mov` version works but wastes an instruction.

---

Your comments are totally redundant, and don't add anything new that isn't already in the instruction itself.  Honestly this code doesn't really need comments, other than maybe to keep track of what's already been added, or just a comment on the final `add` to say
`; eax = bl + bh + ...`.

Normally your comments should be at least one level of abstraction higher than the asm itself; describe the algorithm and how the asm implements it, not what you could look up in the instruction reference manual from looking at the instruction itself.  e.g. if `edx` was holding a value that you were calling `x_distance`, you could comment  `;  eax += x_distance` on the last `add instruction.

In fact, one of the comments isn't even correct, because of too much copy/pasting:

```
movzx   esi, bh         ;copy bh to si and zero out upper part of esi
```

If you really want to describe it that way, you're copying `bh` to `sil` and zeroing the upper 3 bytes.  (`sil` is the low byte of `esi`, only accessible on its own in x86-64 mode).

But really you should think of `movzx` as zero-extending *before* writing to the full ESI, which is good for performance because it doesn't have to merge with the old value and *then* zero extend; it just replaces the old value with the result of zero extending to 32 bits.